# How to deploy web application made up with WebRatio IFML models?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications, web-deployment

I want to deploy my web application made up with WebRatio. More specific, I made a  few  IFML models. 
Does it any free ways to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Although IFML (Interaction Flow Modeling Language) is an international standard approved by OMG, the only valid implementation in order to generate a web project is of Webratio IDE. [IFML Implementation](http://www.ifml.org/implementations/)